# how to add events to elements inside tpl or html in sencha touch 2

Tags: html, sencha-touch

I am trying to add events to the an element inside html(property) in sencha touch 2.0

```
items:[
    {
        html:'<div id="btn" style="height:30px;width:100%;background:green">hello <div/>'
    }
]
```

I tried these ways in controller

```
config: {
    refs: {
        mybtn:'#btn',  ----> i tried (Ext.select('#btn'),Ext.getCmp('btn'),Ext.get('#btn')) 
    },
    control: {
        mybtn:{
            tap:'call'  
        },     
    } 
},

call:function(){
    alert("some thing");
}
```

This doesn't work. Is there any way to do this, or at least how to get these elements in tpl and html property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Controllers do not wire up DOM elements, they only work on Components. You have to listen for the DOM element events in the View Component and then dispatch your own events to the Controller.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251844-Controller-control-and-dom-element-listeners